# Can't use constexpr function of nested class

Tags: c++, c++20, constexpr, static-members

```
struct Foo
{
    struct Bar
    {
        int data = 0;

        //constexpr Bar() = default; // Doesn't work either
        constexpr Bar() : data(0) {}
    };

    static constexpr Bar bar = {}; // ERROR
    //static constexpr Bar bar = {0}; // Works if the ctor from Bar is removed
};
```

Clang and GCC (with std=c++20) say the constructor I'm trying to use is undefined. But it works if I change `constexpr` to `inline`. I would like to understand what is wrong with using 'contexpr'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compiler parses a class in two passes. The first pass handles member variables and function *declarations*, and the second pass handles function *bodies*, which is what allows you to use a member variable (or function) declared below a function in that function.

When classes are nested, the first pass runs over the entire outermost class (including all nested classes), then similarly the second pass over the entire outermost class (including nested ones).

Apparently, static variable initialization happens during the first pass. If it's non-`constexpr` (`inline`), then seeing a constructor declaration is enough. But if it is `constexpr`, then the constructor definition needs to be seen too (to immediately calculate the value), but it isn't available during the first pass.

And when you get rid of the constructor and do `= {0}`, that is *aggregate initialization*, which doesn't use a constructor at all, hence can work during the first pass.

Comment: The current wording of the standard isn't consistent because of the complete-class context rules. See [CWG issue 1255](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/1255.html).

Comment: "_while non-constexpr (inline) static variable initialization happens during the second pass._": It is not that this happens in the second phase (i.e. it doesn't happen in a complete-class context and declarations for everything used need to still appear prior and `Bar` still has to be complete). Rather, the initialization will simply not be a constant expression if the compiler considers the constructor (which is a complete class context) to not be defined yet for `constexpr` purposes, and for just `inline` that's fine. You get dynamic initialization at runtime.

Comment: @user17732522 Aha, thanks. Should be fixed now.